# RSpec: Expecting a method to be called causes that method to not actually be called

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have some code that could be represented in very simple terms as:

```
def method_a(key)
  hash = method b(key)
  hash.delete(key) 
end

def method_b(key)
 return { key => 1 }
end
```

and then an rspec test like

```
it 'calls method_b'
  expect(someClass).to receive(:method_b).with(key)
  method_a(key)
end
```

However I then get an error in the second line of method_a because it's trying to call `delete` on a nil object. When I debug, I can see that the logic inside method_b is never actually being invoked. It's not failing somewhere in method_b, it's literally not calling it at all. If I get rid of the `expect` statement in the test, this error goes away. It seems like the expect statement is causing it to just skip over the actual call to method_b, leaving me with a nil value instead of the hash I'm expecting.

Is there a way I can stop it from skipping over method_b, or at least terminate execution once the expect statement is successful, so I don't run into the error on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a message expectation, it overrides the original code, unless you explicitly tell RSpec not to:

```rb
expect(someClass).to receive(:method_b).with(key).and_call_original
```